# How to put SVGKit in my project

Tags: ios, svgkit

I creat a swift app ,and I want use SVGKit , I follow the steps from GitHub, But I can not

import SVGKit
erro is "no such module SVGKit"

Adition:
so I can not use the kit in my code,
I am new in ios ,maybe something i miss ,please help me ,thanks

so sorry i can not put on my Screenshot，
Kit is from https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

when I type
import SVGKit
in my swift file 
I get the erro  "no such module SVGKit"

Comment: Please include your code and configurations so that others may be able to help you.

Comment: A good idea would be to use cocoa pods, which would do all this dirty work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly; you need to download the SVGKit Project from github. After that you must follow the steps in "Build the static library (automatic)" part. The steps are building the svgkit project getting the release output and importing it to your own project, after that you need to make some configuration in own project. And you must import it in your code with `#import "SVGKit/SVGKit.h"`

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot ,finally, I follow the steps from github, and I find ,my project is a mix one, I should use a bridge between oc and swift,I run my project well end.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps ? i'm new to pods and i'm having hard time adding svgkit pod in my project!!